# Install tiles on top of laminate floor in kitchen

Tags: flooring, kitchens, tile, laminate-floor

This is my remodel kitchen here done 5 years ago.

[image]

Notice that everything is new BUT the floor. As I decided not to do the floor at that time. But now it looks dated.

The kitchen floor is same level as my wood floor.

[image]

Questions:
1. Should I just put tiles on top of the laminate flooring? It will be a bit higher than the wood floor so would it look OK like that?

2. If I remove the laminate piece, what can I do to ensure the level is close?

Comment: What type of tile do you plan on using, ceramic, press-and-stick, vinyl ??

Comment: Often the laminate it raised off the subfloor with and additional layer of plywood to make it level with the wood floor.  Removing that trim between the two may let you see what you've got.

Comment: I have not picked the tiles yet and can be flexible on it if one is thinnest.

Comment: @mikes was asking about the tile type you plan to use, not the thickness.  If you are going with a vinyl adhesive tile you can probably get away with putting it on top, if you want a ceramic or  porcelain tile, you'll need to rip up the old floor.  IMO, I'd tear it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing vinyl flooring and existing underlayment should be removed. All types of ceramic tile, stone tiles, porcelain tiles, etc. need to be installed on a different type of underlayment. Removing the existing underlayment will give you a chance to install the new tile floor level with your wood floor. If not exactly the same level, there are off-set wood covers that can adjust for various heights.